# Why do Americans call hair that turns white ‘gray hair’ instead of ‘white hair’?

Tags: american-english, colors

I searched on YouTube for the reason why hair turns white, and I found that Americans called it *gray hair* not *white hair*.

In my opinion, its color is white, so I don't understand why they call it *gray hair*.

Comment: Do you have any support for your assertion that Americans do that?

Comment: Yes, I do. Take a look at this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_t1-L0qVAJE. I would say those presidents have white hair but the host says they have gray hair.

Comment: Both this [NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=white+hair%2C+grey+hair&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) show that _whte hair_ is actually more used that _grey hair_, so I think you have a wrong premise here.

Comment: I am American - we do say our hair is turning grey... not white.  Good question.

Comment: I think it is just because hair turns grey before it turns white so we talk about the former. That does not mean that we don't call white haired people _white haired_. The video you linked to talks about hair _turning_ grey rather than _grey hair_ in general.

Comment: OK... First I could care less about what NGram ever has as normal.  We are talking about books vs billions of conversations a day.  NGram is iffy at best.  I would never use it as my main supporting piece.  I have lived in America in several regions and hardly anyone refers to it as your hair turning white.  Almost everyone uses grey.  I mean seriously look at the products... Marketing is get rid of your grey hair.

Comment: @RyeBread I agree, the OP stated that Americans refer to _grey hair_ as opposed to _white hair_, that's what I don't buy. Talking about hair _turning_ grey is another matter, see my [previous comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126995/why-do-americans-call-hair-that-turns-white-gray-hair-not-white-hair#comment262041_126995).

Comment: @Anonymous: on your video, I would say those presidents have grey hair, not white. Your premise seems to be more of an opinion.

Comment: @RyeBread: you might not like Ngram, but you not liking it doesn't mean it is wrong. COCA - the Corpus of Contemporary American English - also contradicts your unsupported assertion that "almost everyone uses grey." [Why UK spelling if you are American?] From COCA, gray hair 1084 results; white hair 996. Near enough equal usage.

Comment: @RoaringFish - you think writer's english use represents the population?  There are thousands of examples of words that are never said or even thought during a day but are in books.  I think Ngram and COCA info has its turn in writersSE.

Comment: @RyeBread:- okay... so you are telling us that Ngram is wrong, and COCA is wrong, but we should accept your opinion just because you say so? It doesn't work like that. If you say they are wrong, prove they are wrong. Prove that people in America say 'gray hair' but write 'white hair'. Until you can do that, the corpora are way more convincing than your say so.

Comment: @RoaringFish - I am not saying they are wrong.  I am saying they are a misrepresentation.  There is no data in either database about conversation/dialect.  I don't feel the need to refute something that is so flawed.  I would rather see the urban dictionary as a source - it's probably more current.  Sometimes things have to pass the bullshit test.  For those hazy hazy things we can't sniff out then we can throw in your tools as a tidbit of value.  But that is all they are.  Also you don't even understand what is behind these books in their system.  It doesn't represent modern English.

Comment: @RyeBread:- You are not giving any reason to believe that Americans say "gray hair" in conversation but write "white hair". If you can't do that, then saying COCA is "so flawed" (but "I am not saying they are wrong"?) is nothing more than an unsupported opinion. Why should anyone accept your opinion in preference to large and respected corpora that are widely used for research?

Comment: @RoaringFish - So are you suggesting that google has the keys to our English usage and that we should obey what google says is most used?

Comment: @RyeBread:- I am saying that Ngram and COCA are more reliable than your opinion that you can't support in any way. There is no reason at all to believe that Americans use "gray hair" in conversation but for some mysterious reason switch to "white hair" when they write.

Comment: @RoaringFish - you don't get it.  Your reliance on Ngram and COCA is based on the fact that writers are an almost perfect representation of the English culture and subcultures.  Let me tell you the "educated" writer is not the norm.  Also the "educated" writer is trying to impress and sell his words not use common language.   You are also basing your argument that the books scanned represent the whole or a representation of the whole.  There is nothing I have seen supporting this.  For all I know google subclasses some books as not worthy and disses their data.

Comment: @RyeBread: I do get it. My preference for Ngram and COCA is based on the fact that the sample size is far bigger -450 million words - than your unsupported opinion, and the sample frame far more representative. COCA draws from  spoken language, fiction writing, popular magazines, contemporary newspapers, and from academic texts. What do you draw from?  COCA - > http://llc.oxfordjournals.org/content/25/4/447.abstract

Comment: @RoaringFish - we can agree to disagree.  I personally wouldn't rely on Ngrams or COCA unless I was a robot or shut-in...  But I do need to go reboot.

Comment: @RoaringFish - Yes, the COCA/Ngrams tools search through millions and millions of words, but the two-word phrase "white hair" can be used in plenty of contexts other than the one the O.P. is asking about. I looked a little deeper, and found this on Page 1 of the hits: "Small; generally pale, the femora reddish; abdomen of female banded, of male largely white; thorax of male with dense **white hair**..." It's from a book about horseflies. My point? Sometimes the Ngram's ~450 million word database is _too_ big.

Comment: What's with the limitation to Americans? What do people in the UK call it? Australia? Canada? I'd presume the same, 'gtay' or 'grey'.

Comment: @Mitch Not English I know but in Italy it's usually *brizzolati* or *sale e pepe* (salt and pepper).

Comment: @J.R.:- the absolute numbers don't matter, only how they compare. As long as "grey hair" is used in as many context other than the one the O.P. is asking about the comparison still stands. Given that grey and white are not only both colours, but also similar colours, and both used to describe hair, there is no reason to believe that "white hair" is used in a non-O.P. context any more than "grey hair" is. It is an academic point anyway - COCA is still a lot more credible than RyeBreads opinion.

Comment: RF: How they compare is based on absolute numbers; your logic there is flawed. The Ngram may show that _white hair_ is found in books more than _grey hair_, but so what? There's no way to tell if those books are talking about human hair or goat hair, so, as @Rye said, the graph must be taken with a grain of salt. Point well taken. Lastly, even the relative numbers are probably a lot closer than you think: [have a look](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=white+hair%2Cgray+hair+%2B+grey+hair&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I'm confused about your knowledge of English. What is your langauge history? Were you raised speaking English at home or Italian or what? Which variety of English are you most familiar and did you live speaking it as a child or as an adult? If you didn't grow up with English, when did you pick it up?

Comment: @Mitch  I lived in the UK until I was a teenager, moved, and ever since then I've been "stuck" in Italy. Yes, and by the way I'm confused as well by my own English. Sometimes I need to think before I write down anything. Italiansims have crept up on me over the years.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I realize it may have been impertinent to ask; you keep referring to Italy and Italian (leading me to believe by association you're from Italy), but your writing is native-like and so it was confusing trying to judge your native-like pronouncements. So now I know it is not native-like but native.

Comment: @RoaringFish *Grey* is not “the UK spelling”.  Many Americans have always used *grey* and continue to do so. Stop letting Microsoft reprogram your brain. Furthermore, grey and black and white are exactly the same hue — they are neutral, being an equal mix of all three primary colors of light (red, blue, and green), and you can make any of those look like any of the others under the right conditions. It’s a ridiculous thing to argue about.

Comment: @terdon the results on Ngram change quite dramatically when the word [**gray hair**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=white+hair%2Cgray+hair&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) is added instead. And between grey hair and gray hair we have [these results](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gray+hair%2Cgrey+hair&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: @tchrist but *grey* is the preferred spelling in the UK as shown in this [Ngram result](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gray+suit%2Cgrey+suit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: @tchrist: OED ~ "...different spellings have been selected as standard in U.S. English (gray ) and in British English (generally grey , although individual usage can vary)." *  Etymological Online ~ "The distinction between British grey and U.S. gray developed 20c." * LDOCE ~ "gray
the usual American spelling of  grey" * Etc...   Also ~  COCA: 'gray'= 27948 hits;'grey' = 3811 compared with BNC: 'gray' = 1062 hits; 'grey' = 5406. Recorded usage and lexicographers both say 'gray' is standard in the US and 'grey' in the UK. Note that none of this has anything to do with Microsoft...

Answer (score 5):

Gray (often spelled as *grey* in the UK) is an optical illusion. In actual fact the strands of hair which are always white, only appear gray because they are mixed with the remaining, naturally dark coloured hair. This explains why many people, not only Americans, say they are going gray. Some people never turn completely white haired because some hairs never lose their melanin.

[image]

> As people age, meanocytes slow down their production of melanin or
>   stop working altogether, which results in a lack of pigment. Hair that
>   lacks melanin looks white, **while a mixture of pigmented and
>   unpigmented hair results in a gray appearance.**

<sub>Sources: [*Anatomy and Physiology for Health Professionals*](https://books.google.it/books?id=UdKVBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA116&dq=hair%20physiological%20white%20melanin&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TqWPVa3RIoX3UO-pgZgD&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%20white%20gray%20melanin&f=false) and [*Encyclopedia of Hair: A Cultural History*](https://books.google.it/books?id=9Z6vCGbf66YC&pg=PA148&dq=hair%20white%20melanin%20pigmentation&hl=en&sa=X&ei=56WPVfyvG4flUZmFqIgI&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=hair%20white%20melanin%20pigmentation&f=false)</sub>

Comment: +1 for answering an obvious science/logic question.  +50 more if you don't put an Ngram chart in your answer.

Comment: Actually, *grey* is not “British English”, in that many Americans use it, too, and always have.

Comment: But grey is definitely more common in the UK, it might make an interesting question in the future.

Comment: The wikipedia article doesnt seem to support the statement "In actual fact the strands of hair which are always white, only appear gray because they are mixed with the remaining, naturally dark coloured hair". Where does this come from? In addition white would appear to be a subset of grey, given white is the brightest colour with no chroma and grey is any colour with no chroma. I cannot see how anything could be described as white but not grey.

Comment: @Vality  This was an answer posted nearly two years ago, so could be that Wiki's been edited since then, nevertheless it has this **The clear hairs appear as gray or white because of the way light is reflected from the hairs.**

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am so sorry, I had not noticed the posting was so old. Please accept my apology for assuming. The link I got here from implied it was new and I didn't bother to check the posting date. Regardless, I am assuming you already know this, but it is generally worth adding a quote from a linked article as well as the link just in case it is changed or taken down. But again, sorry for not noticing the age of the post.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If you have no objections would you mind if I edit the post to add in that quote you just commented? Or you could do so yourself if you prefer.

Comment: @Vality well *now* the wikipedia slightly contradicts my answer. I would need to rephrase my answer, but before I do, I should double check whether a hair becomes "clear" or if it actually turns white. The gray/grey part, i.e. the optical illusion, is something I have always believed in.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you very kindly for editing. The new sources are of excellent quality and make the post very much more informative and authoritative.

Comment: Can you replace your screenshot with text? Thanks!

Comment: @Laurel Not now, I'm too tired. I'll try and remember to do it on Sunday

Answer (score 4):

I'm American, and it would never occur to me to call it "white hair," no matter how close to #FFFFFF the color became. Once the hair loses its original color, it's *turned grey*, and, unless you color it, it stays "grey," even when it looks white. Why? I don't know, but there's been a lot of hullaboo about 50 shades of grey lately; maybe the clue lies therein.

---

As for the Ngram that's caused so much ruckus, that's easily explained by clicking on the links beneath the Ngram, and letting Google books dig up and display some sample usages. Most of the examples of "white hair" seemed to be talking from a very scientific point of view, where factual accuracy is presumbly paramount, or else talking about something else entirely:

> However, the tryptophan levels are highest in grey and **[white hair](http://books.google.com/books?id=hLYgFxCuQNoC&pg=PA653&dq=%22white%20hair%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uRk0Uv-BI42H2AX5p4CAAg&ved=0CF0Q6AEwBg)**, showing that tryptophan accumulates among hair fibres with age. Therefore, there is a correlation between tryptophan content and hair pigmentation.
>
> The investigators administered chronic doses of radiolabeled chloropromazine to rabbits and determined the percentage of drug incorporated into black and [**white hair**](http://books.google.com/books?id=ep65US1tiwkC&pg=PA84&dq=%22white%20hair%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uRk0Uv-BI42H2AX5p4CAAg&ved=0CEgQ6AEwAg) by measuring radioactivity of hair samples...

This one comes from a book on raising and showing guinea pigs:

> *Roan* is the even distribution of [**white hair**](http://books.google.com/books?id=09Q7SXrIzPwC&pg=PA8&dq=%22white%20hair%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uRk0Uv-BI42H2AX5p4CAAg&ved=0CGwQ6AEwCQ) with any other colored hair.

and here's a reference where "white hair" refers to "hair on white people":

> Craig also notes that “the dominant interpretation of African American male and female hair straightening has been that it expressed identification with a [**white hair**](http://books.google.com/books?id=YH0EntlW0RcC&pg=PT16&dq=%22white%20hair%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uRk0Uv-BI42H2AX5p4CAAg&ved=0CGEQ6AEwBw) aesthetic.”

So, unsurprisingly, we get a lot of Ngram hits when we look for "white hair", but they don't help us determine what color aging women are thinking of when they buy their first box of hair color, or what word men would use to describe their own salt-and-pepper hair.

---

On the other hand, many of the hits on search for the "grey hair" refer to hair that has lost its original color due to aging:

> In Greek mythology, the power of Medea, the sorceress who fell in love with Jason, leader of the Argonauts, depended on her skill as a perfumer and her ability to use vegetable dye to turn [**grey hair**](http://books.google.com/books?id=RyJk6XFWHxIC&pg=PA8&dq=%22grey%20hair%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3Bk0UqT1DMm62AWM9YGwDQ&ved=0CFgQ6AEwAg) black.
>
> Traditionally, [**grey hair**](http://books.google.com/books?id=YD9LAAAAYAAJ&q=%22grey%20hair%22&dq=%22grey%20hair%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0x00Uv_AMamO2QXUiIG4Bw&ved=0CGoQ6AEwBjge) has been a sign of advancing age. People made a fuss about Barbara Bush's grey hair on the grounds that it made her look more like the President's mother than his wife.
>
> "So, the more you worry about your **[grey hair](http://books.google.com/books?id=YzFxhjIMAWUC&pg=PA16&dq=%22grey%20hair%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5Rw0Ur3qI66s2AX-noGIDA&ved=0CFgQ6AEwAzgK)** the more grey hair you have, and the more grey hair you have the more you worry about it."

Here's one that addresses Mari-Lou's remarks:

> Later in life **[grey hair](http://books.google.com/books?id=HL8pCcKq8eAC&pg=PA58&dq=%22grey%20hair%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3Bk0UqT1DMm62AWM9YGwDQ&ved=0CH8Q6AEwCQ)** develops. The grey colour is usually a result of a mix of coloured hairs and white (non-pigmented) hairs, although sometimes individual 'grey' hairs with reduced pigmentation are found.

I'd conclude that the [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=white%20hair,%20grey%20hair&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) ***supports*** the notion that most Americans call it *grey hair*, although you must do a little detective work, and not form a conclusion just by looking at the two lines.

---

I'm not going to lose any sleep over the fact that I've been (incorrectly?) calling white hair "grey" – after all, we often use imprecise terms when referring to color. Perhaps the sky is blue, the ocean is blue, and the American flag is red, white, and blue, but those blues aren't all the same color. We talk about "black people" and "white people" when really their skintones are more like a rich brown or a pale peach. Many *yellow delicious* apples I've eaten look more [green than yellow](http://www.portstocktonnursery.com/images/normal/Yellow%20Delicious.jpg). We speak of being *red-faced* when we are embarrassed and our skin blushes pink. We order *red wine* that looks closer to byzantium than red, and *white wine* that looks more yellow than white.

---

The Book of Proverbs says:

> The glory of young men is their strength, gray hair the splendor of the old.

I'm old enough to have lost a good bit of my strength, but young enough that I still have my original hair color. No strength, and no splendor. Maybe that's why men my age are so prone to midlife crises.

Comment: With reference to your guinea pigs, 'roan' is also the colour of a horse and probably other animals too. But why are all white horses known as a greys?

Comment: @Mynamite Actually, not all white horses are called grey; In addition to hair colour, horse colour takes into account skin tone, and most apparently-white horses are black-skinned. Or so I've been told by horse-y people of my acquaintance.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps in recent history not many people lived to have white hair but many lived to have grey (white + original color) hair?  I've seen lots of people with grey hair but not all that many with white, so perhaps its a reflection that white-haired elders tend to remain isolated and out of the public eye while many grey-haired people remain in the workforce and thus are seen? Also, bluehair is a derogatory term I've heard used on enough occasions that I remember it.

If you're literally talking about the color of a given person's hair (as opposed to a generalization about older people), I think people use grey or white depending on the actual color. (In other words, I'm trying to say that the "gray-hair" you've heard seems to me to be a generalized and somewhat derogatory term rather than the term that's always used for gray and/or white hair, which is what your question seems to imply.)